# Fully faithful functors between schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a proper morphism of schemes (satsfying some technical conditions), and $f_\ast$ the functor from the category of coherent sheaves on $X$ to coherent sheaves on $Y$ (by pushforward). What are useful necessary and sufficient conditions for $f_\ast$ to be fully faithful? I figure $f$ is a closed immersion suffices. What else?

Comment: I would say that $f$ must be injective on closed points. Otherwise, if $f(x)=f(y)$ and $F_x$, $F_y$ are two skyscraper sheaves on $x$ and $y$, then $Hom(F_x,F_y)=0$ but $Hom(f_*F_x,f_*F_y)$ may not. I also believe that the residue field extension on closed points must be trivial because if $F_x$ is a skyscraper sheaf on $x$ corresponding to a $k(x)$ vector space $F$, then $Hom(F_x,F_x)=Hom_{k(x)}(F,F)$. But $Hom(f_*F_x,f_* F_x)=Hom_{k(f(x))}(F,F)$ so these spaces will not be equal if the field extension is not trivial. Thus I suspect that $f$ is a closed immersion is also necessary.

Comment: That's a quite interesting observation @Roland! thanks